# Set Range is not working

Tags: vba, excel

I've got part of my code in VBA:

```
o = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Set rng = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Range("F2", Cells(o, 6))
A = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If IsError(cell) Then
    A = A + 1
End If
Next
```

However I receive error

> Application-defined or object-defined error

But if I correct it to:

```
o = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Set rng = Range("F2", Cells(o, 6)) 'correction
A = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If IsError(cell) Then
    A = A + 1
End If
Next
```

I have no error- but as I cannot select correct sheet, the code in overall is not working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Cells` function implicitly refers to the `ActiveWorksheet`, try referring to the other workbook explicitly instead.

```
o = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Set rng = Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Range("F2", Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families").Cells(o, 6))
A = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If IsError(cell) Then
        A = A + 1
    End If
Next
```

Alternatively, try using the `Resize` function:

```
With Workbooks(repfile).Worksheets("Families")
    o = .Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Set rng = .Range("F2").Resize(o)
End With
A = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If IsError(cell) Then
        A = A + 1
    End If
Next
```